# Convert date time format in XSLT

Tags: date, datetime, xslt, transform

I have a date value in a field in XML file in this format:

`<Date value="4/1/2013 5:13:41 PM"/>`

I want to convert it into a standard XSD format:

`2013-04-01T17:13:41.000Z`

How can I do that in my XSL transform? I can use both 1.0 and 2.0 stylesheet versions.

Comment: There are number of question with answer available for date format. Have you seen and tried them?

Comment: It depends a little whether 4/1/2013 is 4th January or 1st April. But essentially there's no easy answer, you just have to parse out the components of the date using string manipulation (regexes in XSLT 2.0) and then reassemble the string in the right order. Tedious, but not difficult.

Comment: @MichaelKay: It is clear from the ISO date time string that the date is 1 April.

Answer (score 5):

So...I was bored and hadn't played with [xsl:analyze-string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) before. Here's a regex-based solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/item/date">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="@value" regex="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+) (PM|AM)">

      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="number(regex-group(1))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(regex-group(2))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="year" select="number(regex-group(3))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="hours">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="regex-group(7) = 'PM'">
              <xsl:value-of select="12 + number(regex-group(4))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(4))"/></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="number(regex-group(5))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="number(regex-group(6))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="xs:dateTime( concat($year, '-', format-number($month, '00'), '-', format-number($day, '00'), 'T', format-number($hours, '00'), ':', format-number($minutes, '00'), ':', format-number($seconds, '00'), 'Z')  )" />

        <reformattedDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="$dateTime"/>
        </reformattedDate>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I ran this against a test xml file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<item>
    <date value="4/1/2013 5:13:41 PM"/>
</item>
```

And the output is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <reformattedDate xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2013-04-01T17:13:41Z</reformattedDate>
```

If you want to format the output more precisely, as already recommended, you can use the [format-date function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date).

Comment: I would change `<xsl:variable name="dateTime"><xsl:value-of select="..."/></xsl:variable>` to `<xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="..."/>`.

Comment: Great answer except for 1 point. You missed the 12AM -> 00HH conversion. You can replace  "number(regex-group(4))" with "number(regex-group(4)) mod 12" in the otherwise part for hours

Comment: Shit doesn't work in 1.0. You doo doo. Straight up doo doo like you do.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 version, using `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

Thanks to `adhocgeek` for the XML input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="date"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before(@value, ' ')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="M" select="substring-before($date, '/')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="D-Y" select="substring-after($date, '/')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="D" select="substring-before($D-Y, '/')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="Y" select="substring-after($D-Y, '/')"/>

      <xsl:variable name="time-ampm" select="substring-after(@value, ' ')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-before($time-ampm, ' ')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="ampm" select="substring-after($time-ampm, ' ')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="h" select="substring-before($time, ':')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="m-s" select="substring-after($time, ':')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring-before($m-s, ':')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="s" select="substring-after($m-s, ':')"/>

      <xsl:variable name="hh">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$ampm = 'PM'">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h + 12, '00')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '00')"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>          

      <xsl:value-of select="concat($Y, '-', $M, '-', $D, 'T', $hh, ':', $m, ':', $s)"/>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<item>
  <date value="4/1/2013 5:13:41 PM"/>
</item>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
   <date>2013-4-1T05:13:41</date>
</item>
```

Comment: While I am here: this result is incorrect: `5:13:41 PM` needs to be transformed into `17:13:41`. Otherwise the output will be 12 hours earlier that the input.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ESXLT](http://exslt.org/date/index.html). Many XSL implementations already support the functions out of the box, and they provide fallbacks in case yours does not support it.

If you have fully-compliant implementation, you can do this:

```
<?xml ...
  xmlns.date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
  ...

<xsl:variable name="xsdate" select="date:parse-date(Date/@value, 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a')" />

<xsl:value-of select="$xsdate" />
```

I cheated and used the result of `date:parse` directly. One often uses the `date:format` function to format the date into a particular format.

I've honestly been struggling with getting the "fallback" functions from EXSLT working for me in Apache Xalan. ([Using non-core EXSLT date functions with Xalan Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081400/using-non-core-exslt-date-functions-with-xalan-java))

IMO it would be better to have the date in `xs:dateTime` format in the first place, and convert to some localized format afterward. You can use the `date:format` function to format the date as necessary, and the `date:format` function enjoys much wider support amongst XSLT processors.

Comment: Why don't you post an actual answer, i.e some **code** that would return the required output from the given input? As it happens, I don't know of any EXSLT function that would do that, but then I don't know everything.

Comment: Congratulations, I stand corrected. But which processor supports this function "out of the box"? I don't know of any.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yeah, I don't think there are any, honestly. I haven't checked to see whether the "fallback" options provided by ESXLT will work for `parse-date`. If using Xalan-Java, you can use the technique I used in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081400/using-non-core-exslt-date-functions-with-xalan-java#22157540 and parse-and-reformat the date yourself. Still better-off using `xs:dateTime` dates in your XML in the first place.

Comment: The `<xsl:fallback>` element is designed to handle *elements*, not *functions*. For functions, use the `function-available()` function.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm being sloppy with my nomenclature: I meant ESXLT's "other options" for using their functions when the XSLT implementation does not provide them... not that `<xsl:fallback>` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 2.0 you can construct an `xs:dateTime` value by extracting the components from `Date/@value` using string functions, then you can format if needed using `format-dateTime`: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date. Extracting the date components like year, month, day should be straightforward, obviously for the time you need to some more work to pay attention to the `PM` or `AM` 12-hour clock.

Comment: we could use an actual example here :)

Answer (score 0):

@adhockgeek's answer worked almost perfectly for me.  I only had to add a condition so that it not add 12 to the hour if the value was currently 12.  IE, 12:15 PM != 24:15 AM.

I created a template from his code that can be called repeatedly within a transform:

```
<xsl:template name="FormatDate">
    <xsl:param name="dt"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$dt" regex="([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+) (PM|AM)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="month" select="number(regex-group(1))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(regex-group(2))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="year" select="number(regex-group(3))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="hours">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(7) = 'PM' and regex-group(4) != '12'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="12 + number(regex-group(4))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(4))"/></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="number(regex-group(5))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="number(regex-group(6))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(concat($year, '-', format-number($month, '00'), '-', format-number($day, '00'), 'T', format-number($hours, '00'), ':', format-number($minutes, '00'), ':', format-number($seconds, '00')))" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$dateTime"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code with substring-before and substring-after works, but more checks should be added:
12AM => 00 and 12PM => 12 something like this:

```
 <xsl:variable name="hh">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$ampm = 'AM' and $h='12'">00</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$ampm = 'PM' and $h!='12'">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h + 12, '00')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '00')"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
```